# LINQ to SQL deleting record referenced by foreign key

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a Customers table, a Sports table, and Customers_Sports join table. The last table tells me which customers play what sports, ie contains foreign keys to the other two tables.

Foreign key constraints are enforced, and foreign keys cannot be null.

Using LINQ, is there a simple way to delete a customer and at the same time delete all the records in the join table that reference the customer?

I can do it the hard way, ie first delete relevant records from the join table, then delete the customer's record from Customers.

Comment: Is it within the scope of the project to set up the database to cascade deletes?

Comment: I could indeed set up the database to do cascade deletes, but I assumed (or hoped) that LINQ to SQL would provide the required "smarts".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Simple* is the real kicker.  [There's not an automatic way to do it.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386931.aspx)  You're basically stuck deleting everything from the Customer_Sports table that matches the given customer, then deleting the customer yourself.  I believe if you delete both before you do a `SubmitChanges()` you shouldn't run into any foreign key constraint violations.

If you wanted to get really fancy you could use reflection to create a generic function that would do this any time there was a foreign key kind of like [Linq to SQL cascading delete with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531693/linq-to-sql-cascading-delete-with-reflection) .

Setting up the database to do this for you is probably a lot less error prone.  The performance is probably better too, although unless you know you have a performance problem you shouldn't worry about performance.

Comment: Yes, in a depressing sort of way.